# Nodejs - Pipe multi inputs to a spawned process

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

As we all know, we can pipe a stream to spawn child process.

Just do like this:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const { spawn } = require('child_process')
const child = spawn('ffmpeg', '-i pipe:0 -f h264 pipe:1').split(' '),{
  stdio: ['pipe','pipe','ignore']
})
const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./a.h264')
readStream.pipe(child.stdin)
child.stdout.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./b.h264')
```

But how could I pipe two different input to the child?

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs');
const child = spawn(
  'ffmpeg',
  `-i pipe:0 -i pipe:1 -acodec aac -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest -movflags frag_keyframe+separate_moof+omit_tfhd_offset+empty_moov -f mp4 pipe:2`.split(' '),
  {
    stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'ignore']
  }
);
const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./a.ulaw');
const readStream1 = fs.createReadStream('./b.h264');
readStream.pipe(child.stdio[0]);
readStream1.pipe(child.stdio[1]);
child.stdio[2].pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./c.mp4'));
```

Comment: Just create an array of file names you need piped, in order, and then pipe them one by one using a forEach, _inside_ of which you do your createReadStream and pipe call? Although since you're calling ffmpeg anyway, just feed ffmpeg the list of file paths directly, and let _it_ figure out the rest (it's kind of an infinite swiss army knife that way).

Comment: There are two stream(which are both not filestream) come and I need to put them together, but the spawn seems just has one input. could you give me an example?

Comment: Just literally do that? Set up an array of however many streams, in order, and then loop over them (e.g. `[stream1, stream2, ...].forEach(s => pipe "s" into ffmpeg`)